# asyncio queue consumer coroutine

Tags: python, python-3.x, coroutine, python-asyncio

I have a `asyncio.Protocol` subclass receiving data from a server.
I am storing this data (each line, because the data is text) in a `asyncio.Queue`.

```
import asyncio

q = asyncio.Queue()

class StreamProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, loop):
        self.loop = loop
        self.transport = None

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport

    def data_received(self, data):
        for message in data.decode().splitlines():
            yield q.put(message.rstrip())

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        self.loop.stop()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = loop.create_connection(lambda: StreamProtocol(loop),
                              '127.0.0.1', '42')
loop.run_until_complete(coro)
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

I want to have another coroutine responsible for consuming the data in the queue and processing it.

- Should this be a `asyncio.Task`?
- What if the queue becomes empty because for a few seconds no data is received? How can I make sure my consumer doesn't stop (`run_until_complete`)?
- Is there a cleaner way than using a global variable for my queue?

Comment: Your code is wrong, sorry: `data_received` should be regular function, not a coroutine with `yield` inside. Moreover `asyncio.Queue` requires `yield from`, not just `yield`.

Comment: Ah right. I put that there without testing it just to give the idea of what i wanted to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Should this be a asyncio.Task?

Yes, create it using [asyncio.ensure_future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.ensure_future) or [loop.create_task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.create_task).

> What if the queue becomes empty because for a few seconds no data is received?

Simply use [queue.get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue.get) to wait until an item is available:

```
async def consume(queue):
    while True:
        item = await queue.get()
        print(item)
```

> Is there a cleaner way than using a global variable for my queue?

Yes, simply pass it as argument to the consumer coroutine and stream protocol:

```
class StreamProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, loop, queue):
        self.loop = loop
        self.queue = queue

    def data_received(self, data):
        for message in data.decode().splitlines():
            self.queue.put_nowait(message.rstrip())

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        self.loop.stop()
```

> How can I make sure my consumer doesn't stop (run_until_complete)?

Once the connection is closed, use [queue.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue.join) to wait until the queue is empty.

---

Full example:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
queue = asyncio.Queue()
# Connection coroutine
factory = lambda: StreamProtocol(loop, queue)
connection = loop.create_connection(factory, '127.0.0.1', '42')
# Consumer task
consumer = asyncio.ensure_future(consume(queue))
# Set up connection
loop.run_until_complete(connection)
# Wait until the connection is closed
loop.run_forever()
# Wait until the queue is empty
loop.run_until_complete(queue.join())
# Cancel the consumer
consumer.cancel()
# Let the consumer terminate
loop.run_until_complete(consumer)
# Close the loop
loop.close()
```

Alternatively, you can also use [streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html?highlight=streams#tcp-echo-client-using-streams):

```
async def tcp_client(host, port, loop=None):
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(host, port, loop=loop)
    async for line in reader:
        print(line.rstrip())
    writer.close()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(tcp_client('127.0.0.1', 42, loop))
loop.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like the right way to do it. I think there's a problem with your full example, the `coro` variable doesn't exist

Comment: @toogy True, I just fixed it.

Comment: Perfect. Just one last thing. What if I want my consumer to be more than a function (I mean a class)? Should I simply inherit the `asyncio.Task` class?

Comment: @toggy No, just have your class define coroutines that you can schedule as task using `asyncio.ensure_future`.

Comment: Thanks again Vincent

Comment: May I ask how, using this scenario, one would go about running the comms as a server in its own thread.  Main thread creates the event loop, recvQ; sendQ (import queue) and passes them as args to comms thread.  The TCP protocol has only 3 methods: connection_made; data_received; connection_lost.   I raised question 42949622 but have little in response.   Main task should queue data for sending and receive data once the data_received method forwards it (standard queue put and get both ends).